# Dynamically created dropdowns and fired events accordingly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple task. first one Dropdownlist control is there where country name is loaded. After selecting country name, dynamically Dropdownlist will be loaded with corresponding state, after selecting state, dynamically another Dropdownlist will be added with relevant district. the problem is that the dynamically selected-index event is not fired. I searched it so many pages, but not find any suitable answer. can any one answer it for written code.

This code worked fine in static controls. but not dynamic controls.
Can any one correct my code

```
namespace fireProgram
 {
    public partial class MindforeSystemTestingProgram : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
      BALayer objBALayer = new BALayer();
      DropDownList ddlState=new DropDownList();
      DropDownList ddlDistrict=new DropDownList();
    protected void Page_Init(EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlState.ID = "ddlState";
        ddlState.AutoPostBack = true;
        ddlState.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged);
        panel1.Controls.AddAt(2, ddlState);


        ddlDistrict.ID = "ddlDistrict";
        panel1.Controls.AddAt(3, ddlDistrict);      
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlCountry.DataSource = objBALayer.GetCountry();
            ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Text";
            ddlCountry.DataValueField = "Value";
            ddlCountry.DataBind();
        }
        //else
        //{              
        //    ddlState.ID = "ddlState";
        //    ddlState.AutoPostBack = true;
        //    ddlState.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged);
        //    panel1.Controls.AddAt(2, ddlState);


        //    //ddlDistrict.ID = "ddlDistrict";
        //    //panel1.Controls.AddAt(3, ddlDistrict);
        //}
    }

    protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);           
        panel1.Controls.AddAt(2, ddlState);
        //DropDownList ddlState = new DropDownList();                               
        //ddlState.AutoPostBack = true;
        if (value != 0)
        {
            ddlState.DataSource = objBALayer.GetState(value);
            ddlState.DataTextField = "Text";
            ddlState.DataValueField = "Value";
            ddlState.DataBind();
        }                      
    }   
    protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue);           
        //DropDownList ddlDistrict = new DropDownList()
        panel1.Controls.AddAt(3, ddlDistrict);
        if (value != 0)
        {
            ddlDistrict.DataSource = objBALayer.GetDistrict(value);
            ddlDistrict.DataTextField = "Text";
            ddlDistrict.DataValueField = "Value";
            ddlDistrict.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I would try setting the SelectedIndexChanged handler AFTER adding the control to the panel (I must confess that's a real blind shot) If this does not succeed, I would try to swap the _AddAt_s with _Add_s and see what happens